# check if year in string is = or bigger than 2017

Tags: php

I have many posts and I want to add some special offer in the ones that I post this year.

```
offer name - July 20, 2015
offer name - July 20, 2016
offer name - July 20, 2017
...
```

I'm doing this:

```
$a = "offer name - July 20, 2000";
if (preg_match('/2017/',$a)) {
    echo 'offer';
}
```

it is working for 2017, but I want to add offers in posts from 2017 and next years... 18, 19.
any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This variant iterates over the input and filters by year:

```
<?php
$input = [
  'offer name - July 20, 2015',
  'offer name - July 20, 2016',
  'offer name - July 20, 2017'
];
$output = [];
array_walk($input, function($entry) use (&$output){
  if (   preg_match('| - \w+\s+\d+,\s+(\d+)$|', $entry, $tokens)
      && intval($tokens[1]) >= 2017 ) {
    $output[] = $entry;
  }
});
print_r($output);
```

This is a somewhat more compact variant:

```
<?php
$input = [
  'offer name - July 20, 2015',
  'offer name - July 20, 2016',
  'offer name - July 20, 2017'
];
$output = array_filter($input, function($entry){
  return
         preg_match('| - \w+\s+\d+,\s+(\d+)$|', $entry, $tokens)
      && (intval($tokens[1]) >= 2017);
});
print_r($output);
```

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => offer name - July 20, 2017
)
```

Comment: It may look complex at first to people not that fluent in dynamic languages, but it is a pattern that has proven to be reliable and secure for such tasks: it offers a clean separation of the filter logic from the rest of your code.

Answer (score 2):

you can use something like that

```
function isYearAllowed($date, array $allowedYears)
{
    try {
        $date = new \DateTime($date);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
    if(in_array($date->format("Y"), $allowedYears)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

Example of usage

```
$allowedYears = ['2017','2016'];
if(isYearAllowed("2016-12-31", $allowedYears)){
    echo "offer";
}else{
    echo "don't offer";
}
exit;
```

live demo (https://eval.in/835914)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `substr` and `intval` function to achieve the same.

Following is working code. You can see it working [here](http://ideone.com/SY7jSA):

```
<?php
$val = array("offer name - July 20, 2000", "offer name - July 20, 2017","offer name - July 20, 2018");
foreach($val as $a)
{
    $b = substr($a,strlen($a)-4, 4);
    if(intval($b)>= 2017)
    {
        echo "Offer";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No Offer";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the date function to extract the year from the date string and then directly compare it to `2017` as the value it should be equal to or greater than.

This function provides that basic functionality whereas it returns `TRUE` if the year is greater than or equal to `2017`, else it returns `FALSE`

```
function validate_year($in_string_date){

  // Particular to the case in this question, format date for date() function    
  $in_string_date = str_replace(',','',$in_string_date);    
  $in_string_date = str_replace(' ','-',$in_string_date);

  $valid_year = FALSE;

  // Get the year component from the date passed into the function.
  $year_in_date = date('Y',strtotime($in_string_date));

  /* Check if the year component extracted from the date passed
     to the function is greater or ewual to 2017 */
  if($year_in_date >= 2017){
    $valid_year = TRUE;
  }

  return $valid_year;
}
```

Comment: thank you! but something is wrong in this line: `$year_in_date = ('Y',strtotime($in_string_date));` FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected ','

Comment: I just tested with the latest edits, it responds with a 1 for true or 0 for false.

Answer (score 1):

There may be an easier way to do this but until you find it you could try doing a while loop.

1) Set a variable to the starting year, you could do this static or by the year time function in php `date("Y")`.

2)

```
while('your variable'){ //will always be true
             if (preg_match('/'.'your variable'.'/')) //if there is an offer for this year
             {
                 echo 'offer';
                 'your variable'++;
             }
             else
             {
               break;
             }
        }
```

It may not be what your looking for but it should work.

Comment: Trying to get the meaning of that last sentence in your answer... _if_ that is _not_ what the OP is looking for, then what does "it should work" actually mean?

Comment: It is a rather simple solution, although initially I forgot to make sure it was incrementing, and it may not be a method that he wants to use since every method has its pros and cons.

Comment: Sorry, but I still cannot make much sense of this "pseudo code". It iterates something, but for what purpose? And it does not address the actual issue at all which is how to extract the year number from some string.

Comment: What it is doing is checking the string for whatever args are placed in preg_match. The loop is to start with the current year and increment until you don't have matching data for a subsequent year.

Comment: Like i said may not be what he is looking for because I knew there are other solutions, it's just the quickest easiest one I could think of where he wouldn't have to have any static code to change in subsequent years, since you can set your variable with the date function provided by php.

Comment: So you actually simply recommend to use the current year for comparison instead of a hard coded number. Yep, good suggestion, indeed.